# Ubuntu won't load from usb

Tags: boot, system-installation

I'm trying to install ubuntu 14.04. I set in my bios for it to load from the usb and once it starts loading this screen pops up and stays there, it won't go past this screen.

[image]

Comment: try to create bootable Ubuntu usb through unetbootin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create bootable Ubuntu usb using [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

Comment: Did not work, still get the same problem

Comment: Works now, I had to boot into windows then run from the usb and do a reboot and is now working.

Comment: Welcome. You can vote up for support.